# Combining different content types

Tags: nodes

I do not have much experience with Drupal but I have a question. 
I have a content type Hotels with general information about the hotel but also with a field country and country information. 
I was thinking to make a content type Country with fields like country information (country Name (England), country description (England is an island), map (googlemaps). 
So when I have to add 10 hotels in the same country I do not have to write the same country information again and again. 
I want to combine the content type HOTEL and COUNTRY but I really don't know how to do it?

Comment: Your acceptance rate is at 0%. Consider accepting the best answers for the questions you posted so the help you received can help others. You may also upvote the answers you deem relevant / helpful.  YOu can find more details of how this community ticks in the awesome [faq page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq).  Well worth reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set up two content types, "Hotel" and "Country" and use the [Entity References](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to define a relationship between the two. Then configure it to display a "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a configurable view mode

Comment: Thank you for the response but in the taxonomy for the country are different items then just text. There will be a country Name (England), country description (England is an island), map (googlemaps) And i don't know if this is possible with taxonomy.

Comment: Ah makes sense now. I have edited your question to further clarify what you are trying to accomplish and have edited my answer to better provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For addresses you could use the [location](http://drupal.org/project/location) or [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) modules. That will help you don't the road when you integrate with other modules, like gmaps.

The [references](https://drupal.org/project/references) module is a another good option.